# Durandal 2.0 "routes"

Tags: javascript, durandal, hottowel, durandal-navigation, durandal-2.0

I'm a Beginner trying to learn SPA / Durandal, Knockout etc...

Need some help with my routes for a **Admin** drop down button.

Here are my routes in the **shell.js** so far:

```
var routes = [
            { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'Home', nav: 1 },
            { route: 'downtime', moduleId: 'downtime', title: 'Downtime', nav: 2 },
            { route: 'downtimeadd', moduleId: 'downtimeadd', title: 'Add A New Downtime', nav: false, settings: { admin: true } },
            { route: 'production', moduleId: 'production', title: 'Production', nav: 4 }];
```

I've also created **adminRoutes** in the **shell.js** to bind to the view with KO:

```
var adminRoutes = ko.computed(function () {
        return router.routes.filter(function (r) {
            return r.settings.admin;
        });
    });
```

From research, they say that **router.routes** is an array, but when I bind this to my view the button shows 0 items for the drop down.

When I do (below) I can get all the routes, but I only need the admin routes...

```
var adminRoutes = ko.computed(function () {
        return router.routes;
    });
```

How should I proceed? It seems like **router.routes** is not actually an array?
If I try to print it out to the console:

```
console.log(router.routes[0]); //Chrome says its undefined...
console.log(router.routes); //Shows array of size 4...
```

Yup no clue... Help would be appreciated!

**Update:**-------------------------------------------------------------------

Even after RainerAtSpirit's suggestions I still get an empty array when I filter in code.

```
var router = require('plugins/router');
//Array size 4
console.log(router.routes); 

//Array size 0
console.log(router.routes.filter(function (r) { return r; }));
```

However when I run this in the "**chrome console**":

```
var router = require('plugins/router')
router.routes.filter(function (r) { return r; })
```

I do get the array back, so I don't know why in code it doesn't work.

Comment: Check here  for an answer that should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665615/how-to-use-dropdowns-for-durandal-navigation/17666712#17666712

Comment: Looks like the filter doesn't work because it's testing against `r.setting.admin`, but `settings` is not defined in every config. If you get rid of the settings object e.g. just use `admin: true` the approach will work.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit If my understanding is correct, if changed my route from `settings: { admin: true }` to `admin: true`, and filter by `r.admin` I still get a 0 array.

Comment: To test, even if I filter by `title: 'Add A New Downtime'` then `return r.title === 'Add A New Downtime'` I still get a 0 array even though I can bind to the view and return the title.

Comment: Hmh: go to dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/. in console connect to router via `var router =  require('plugins/router')`. For me this  `router.routes.filter(function(route){ return route.admin });` is working.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit Updated post. I'm not sure what is going on. Why it works in chrome console and not from the code.

Comment: Sounds weird. Try forking the dFiddle and reproduce so that we can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, although maybe not as perfectly as I would like.

The first problem I noticed was an issue that others were not seeing.  In my example (with druandal 2.0 from the HotTowel template version 1.1 for VS 2013) I noticed that this code for adding the adminRoutes was called prior to the activate method.  Therefore, my route.routes was an empty array.  To fix this problem, I switched to just using the array of routes that the routes are getting mapped from the config.js with (note: config.routes rather than route.routes):

```
var adminRoutes = ko.computed(function () {
    return config.routes.filter(function(r) {
        return r.admin;
    });
});
```

Finally, I'm return "r.admin".  This is the part that would like to make work better because I added an admin property to the admin route without the "settings" group, see "**admin: true**":

```
var routes = [
    { route: '', moduleId: 'equipment', title: 'Equipment', nav: 1 },
    { route: 'testresults', moduleId: 'testresults', title: 'Test Results', nav: 2 },
    { route: 'testresultdetail/:id', moduleId: 'testresultdetail', title: 'View a test result', nav: false },
    { route: 'testresultadd', moduleId: 'testresultadd', title: 'Add a Test Result', nav: false, caption: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Test Result', admin: true }
];
```

With these two changes, the menu item showed up.

Answer (score 0):

In knockout when you make a property  to be observable it turns in to a function wrapping ,so when you need to get the actual value you need to access it as a function. That means

`router.routes[0]` will be undefined but `router.routes()[0]` will work correct !

You can try

```
var adminRoutes = ko.computed(function () {
        return router.routes().filter(function (r) {
            return r.settings.admin;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Good advice and true in many cases, but this time it' wrong as router.routes  is an array . http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#class/Router/property/routes